# How to know if there is an internet disconnection in the response of an API request with OkHttp3 in Android?

Tags: android, okhttp

Let say the codes already checked for internet connection right before making an API request. The internet was fine and so the request was made. However, while waiting for the response, an internet disconnection happened.

The request was made using OkHttp3 in Android. How can I know if the cause of the failure was because of an internet disconnection? Do the OkHttp3 Response class or the IOException have something to indicate the issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check internet connection OKHTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40389163/check-internet-connection-okhttp)

Comment: @SidharthMudgil No, that answer is used to check the connection at the time the function is called. It does not check AFTER the API request is already made. The internet could be available when the request is made, but it could be disconnected BEFORE the response arrives. I would like to check for that case, i.e get the reason the request is failed (Internet disconnection in this case)